# Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm NN training (backpropagation)

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, backpropagation

I'm currently looking into the different training methods of NN. I've implemented a simple gradient descent method using backpropagation in my NN (just a very simple NN with 1 hidden layer). I'm now struggling with implementing a more sophisticated training (weights and biases) algorithm, i.e. the Levenberg-Marquardt. Is there also such an elegant method which uses backpropagation to calculate the jacobian?

Edit: I've found [1] which is a really interesting article and is almost what I'm looking for. Nevertheless, I don't understand how I propagate through the different layers because I only have the error $e$ for the last layer (output layer). However, I want to adjust two weigth matrices (from input to hidden layer and from hidden layer to output).

[1] M. T. Hagan and M. B. Menhaj, "Training feedforward networks with the Marquardt algorithm," in IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks, vol. 5, no. 6, pp. 989-993, Nov. 1994, doi: 10.1109/72.329697.

Comment: You should look at how Eric Wan's diagrammatic Jacobian works.  For the adjoint network the outbound elements become inbound elements with a sum.  You add up all the incoming errors and then you can run it through the Jacobian with respect to those values to estimate the directions that the weights should go.  Wan, E. A., & Beaufays, F. (1997, September). Diagrammatic methods for deriving and relating temporal neural network algorithms. In International School on Neural Networks, Initiated by IIASS and EMFCSC (pp. 63-98). Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Comment: This work doesn't really provide more information than the one I've mentioned. I'm currently calculating the Jacobian AND the gradient to calculate do the Levenberg-Marquardt learning (using backpropagation). However, I think there is a more efficient way.

Comment: And I do not understand your problem going from the multiple links between the hidden layer and output later. It should be straightforward to communicate the error across those links.

Comment: Obviously, it's not for me. That's exactly the thing that bothers me. I see and understand the derivation of the backpropagation of the gradient and Jacobian (with the derivatives and so on). It should be even easier to backpropagate the error but sadly I just don't see it.